# нагрузочный тест на java

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, testng, асинхронность

Есть сервер, есть тестовый клиент. Клиент посылает один запрос и получает один ответ. Необходимо переделать клиент таким образом, чтобы он делал нагрузочное тестирование.

Что надо сделать:

1) Количество пользователей, которых надо сымитировать: N
2) Количество возможных действий пользователя: M
-- на каждое действие есть действующий тест
-- в общей сложности надо сделать 100 тыс или 1 млн запросов
3) Все это должно выполняться асинхронно.
4) Статистика должна записываться в файл

Я ума не приложу, как к этому подступиться?

Comment: 1млн запросов асихнхронно...Используйте технологию Future в Java для этого. А так. Ваш код в студию, пожалуйста.

Comment: 1 млн - это всего, можно меньше, можно 100 тыс. Надо же нагрузку сервера проверить. Надо 8-16 потоков. А вот код показать не могу - меня уволят тогда на хрен) Мне бы принцип понять, как это сделать)

Comment: почитайте про http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я хочу вам напомнить, что вы забываете принимать ответы, данные к вашим вопросам. По правилам SO желательно принимать ответы, которые решают ваши проблемы. Для принятия ответа нажмите на галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: Почитай про jmeter. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html вот тут есть примерно вся информация которая нужная для начала. Дальше, по ходу дела, разберёшься.

Comment: Anton Sorokin, я не забываю, а просто понятия не имею, как это делать)